# Blob URL upload to firebase storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-storage, blob

I'm using "react-image-crop" (https://github.com/DominicTobias/react-image-crop) for cropping an image and then upload it to Firebase storage. The response from "react-image-crop" is a blob:URL in my state. When I call:

```
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
        var mountainImagesRef = storageRef.child(
            "images/" + auth.uid + "/avatar.jpg"
        );
        mountainImagesRef.put(file).then(function(snapshot) {...
```

I get the error:

```
Firebase Storage: Invalid argument in `put` at index 0: Expected Blob or File.
```

I know that I need to pass a blob or file and not the URL but how can I fix this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed that, by editing the returned Promise of "react-image-crop".
Change return Promise to:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            canvas.toBlob(blob => {
                if (!blob) {
                    //reject(new Error('Canvas is empty'));
                    console.error("Canvas is empty");
                    return;
                }
                blob.name = fileName;
                console.log(blob);
                resolve(blob);
            }, "image/jpeg");
        });
```

Now you will get a blob returned and not a blob url.

Comment: where are you getting the fileName from?

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the blob from an image URL through a fetch request:

```
async blobFromURL(url) {
 blob = await fetch(this.imageUrl).then(r => r.blob());
 return blob
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm still getting the error. The return is a Promise, can this be the reason for the error?

Comment: The fetch request is asynchronous, you need to wait for it to be resolved before uploading it.

I never used this plugin but there seems to be a straightforward way to retrieve a blob instead of a url on the documentation:

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    canvas.toBlob(blob => {
      blob.name = fileName;
      resolve(blob);
    }, 'image/jpeg', 1);
  });